# TypeError: decompress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_path'

Tags: python, compression, typeerror, huffman-code

Error keeps appearing as seen in the title, this one has stumped me. The compression function works without any errors but there is a `TypeError` every time `but_decomp` is called.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os        
import heapq


class HuffmanCoding:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.heap = []
        self.codes = {}
        self.reverse_mapping = {}

    class HeapNode:
        def __init__(self, char, freq):
            self.char = char
            self.freq = freq
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

        # defining comparators less_than and equals
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.freq < other.freq

        def __eq__(self, other):
            if (other == None):
                return False
            if (not isinstance(other, HeapNode)):
                return False
            return self.freq == other.freq

    # functions for compression:

    def make_frequency_dict(self, text):
        frequency = {}
        for character in text:
            if not character in frequency:
                frequency[character] = 0
            frequency[character] += 1
        return frequency

    def make_heap(self, frequency):
        for key in frequency:
            node = self.HeapNode(key, frequency[key])
            heapq.heappush(self.heap, node)

    def merge_nodes(self):
        while (len(self.heap) > 1):
            node1 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
            node2 = heapq.heappop(self.heap)

            merged = self.HeapNode(None, node1.freq + node2.freq)
            merged.left = node1
            merged.right = node2

            heapq.heappush(self.heap, merged)

    def make_codes_helper(self, root, current_code):
        if (root == None):
            return

        if (root.char != None):
            self.codes[root.char] = current_code
            self.reverse_mapping[current_code] = root.char
            return

        self.make_codes_helper(root.left, current_code + "0")
        self.make_codes_helper(root.right, current_code + "1")

    def make_codes(self):
        root = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        current_code = ""
        self.make_codes_helper(root, current_code)

    def get_encoded_text(self, text):
        encoded_text = ""
        for character in text:
            encoded_text += self.codes[character]
        return encoded_text

    def pad_encoded_text(self, encoded_text):
        extra_padding = 8 - len(encoded_text) % 8
        for i in range(extra_padding):
            encoded_text += "0"

        padded_info = "{0:08b}".format(extra_padding)
        encoded_text = padded_info + encoded_text
        return encoded_text

    def get_byte_array(self, padded_encoded_text):
        if len(padded_encoded_text) % 8 != 0:
            print("Encoded text not padded properly")
            exit(0)

        b = bytearray()
        for i in range(0, len(padded_encoded_text), 8):
            byte = padded_encoded_text[i:i + 8]
            b.append(int(byte, 2))
        return b

    def compress(self):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)
        output_path = filename + ".bin"

        with open(self.path, 'r+') as file, open(output_path, 'wb') as output:
            text = file.read()
            text = text.rstrip()

            frequency = self.make_frequency_dict(text)
            self.make_heap(frequency)
            self.merge_nodes()
            self.make_codes()

            encoded_text = self.get_encoded_text(text)
            padded_encoded_text = self.pad_encoded_text(encoded_text)

            b = self.get_byte_array(padded_encoded_text)
            output.write(bytes(b))

        print("Compressed")
        return output_path

    """ functions for decompression: """

    def remove_padding(self, padded_encoded_text):
        padded_info = padded_encoded_text[:8]
        extra_padding = int(padded_info, 2)

        padded_encoded_text = padded_encoded_text[8:]
        encoded_text = padded_encoded_text[:-1 * extra_padding]

        return encoded_text

    def decode_text(self, encoded_text):
        current_code = ""
        decoded_text = ""

        for bit in encoded_text:
            current_code += bit
            if current_code in self.reverse_mapping:
                character = self.reverse_mapping[current_code]
                decoded_text += character
                current_code = ""

        return decoded_text

    def decompress(self, input_path):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)
        output_path = filename + "_decompressed" + ".txt"

        with open(input_path, 'rb') as file, open(output_path, 'w') as output:
            bit_string = ""

            byte = file.read(1)
            while (len(byte) > 0):
                byte = ord(byte)
                bits = bin(byte)[2:].rjust(8, '0')
                bit_string += bits
                byte = file.read(1)

            encoded_text = self.remove_padding(bit_string)

            decompressed_text = self.decode_text(encoded_text)

            output.write(decompressed_text)

        print("Decompressed")
        return output_path


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.config(background="white")
        self.path = None
        self.label_file_explorer = tk.Label(self, text="Menu", fg="blue",
                                            width="300", height="2",
                                            font="Helvetica 20 bold")
        self.label_file_explorer.pack()
        self.button_explore = tk.Button(self, text="Browse Files", fg="blue",
                                        font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE, width=20,
                                        command=self.browse_files)
        self.button_explore.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_exit = tk.Button(self, text="Close Program", width=20,
                                     font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                     # destroy root
                                     command=self.master.destroy)
        self.button_exit.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_compress = tk.Button(self, text="Compress", width=20,
                                         font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                         command=self.but_comp)
        self.button_compress.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.button_decompress = tk.Button(self, text="Decompress", width=20,
                                           font="Arial 15", relief=tk.GROOVE,
                                           command=self.but_decomp)
        self.button_decompress.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def browse_files(self):
        file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                               title="Select a File",
                                               filetypes=(("all files", "*.*"),
                                                          ("text files", "*.txt*")))

        if file_name == "":  # if Cancel
            return
        else:
            self.label_file_explorer.configure(text="Selected File: " + file_name)
            self.path = file_name

    def but_comp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.compress()

    def but_decomp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.decompress()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Compression Utility")
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
# the last path stored in the data attribute
# of the instance of the Application class
print(app.path)
```

Comment: So, what should the `input_path` be and why don't you supply that as an argument?

Comment: You defined `def decompress(self, input_path)` but then you didn't provide a pathname when you called it.

Comment: What file do you want to decompress?

Comment: @Barmar I want to compress any `.txt` file. Any sample text file will do. You select a file from the file explorer then compress it. It then creates a `.bin` file using Huffman's coding. After that, you open the file explorer again and select the .bin file you just created. The click decompress, then it should reverse map everything remove padded bits and create a new `.txt` file which is identical to the original with a new name of `xxx_decompressed.txt`.

Comment: Then pass the selected filename as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variable through the function. `input_path` passed through `.decompress`.

```
 def but_decomp(self):
        if self.path:
            H = HuffmanCoding(self.path)
            H.decompress(input_path = self.path)
```